# Where does Azure Event Hub Store the data they are ingested with?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventhub, azure-data-lake

Just Finished One of the Course in MVA "Hands-On with Azure Stream Analytics" . But somehow it doesn't clear the concept, how does event hub storing the data or where it's store that data its getting, whether BLOB Store or Data lake, or can we change this type of store its doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Event Hub is a PaaS (Platform as a Service), you do not need to care where the data is stored. You just use the service, and the platform makes sure it can meet your traffic based  on the configured scaling units. They take care of storing data in a highly available, durable and redundant storage. This is all you need to know about storage behind Event Hubs.